# How can I get the coefficient of the exponent from a nonlinear model fit?

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I have been trying for over an hour now to get the numeric value for `"HalfLifeN"` from the code in the screenshot below.  Not to mention mathematica simplifies $e^{ln(x)}$ to $ 2^x$, which I don't want it to do.

I can work through this by hand, but I would really prefer not to.  Is there any way I can access the values of `"HalfLifeN"` even though they are internal to the nlmf function?

Thank you.

[image]

My temporary workaround was to use a different variable not dependent of Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjL80.png), and then copy and past it to solve for the half life.
[image]

Comment: Please provide **code** instead of screenshots. This will make dealing with your input _much_ easier.

Answer (score 8):

```
Flatten[#["BestFitParameters"][[All, 2]] & /@ {data1Fit, data2Fit, data3Fit}]
```

or

```
{HalfLife1, HalfLife2, HalfLife3 } /.
   Flatten[ #["BestFitParameters"] &/@ {data1Fit, data2Fit, data3Fit}]
```